# Swift: текстовые элементы таблицы - как задавать значения одному ссылаясь на значения в другом?

Tags: swift, uitableview, передача-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите пожалуйста решить задачку!
Есть view, в нём создан tableView, в котором определённое количество проиндексированных через extention ячеек.

В каждый ячейке есть её номер, label и ещэ один label. Есть отдельно созданный Root, там есть массив, из которого берём данные тоже. И есть куча формул, просчитывающие значения для отдельных переменных, значения которых надо разложить первый label по порядку, в соответствии с номерами. Поняла только как всё оформить и показать во вью. А как теперь соединить это всё?

class YearsViewController: UIViewController {

```
private let fileReadManager = FileReaderManager()
var peremennaya = ""
// и таких переменных 76 штук

@IBOutlet weak var secondTable: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//Здесь включается метод из модели и под каждую переменную отрабатываются свои расчёты
```

}

```
    let identifier = "BirthCell"
    let array = ["0", "1-2", "2-3", "3-4", "5", "6-7", "7-8", "8-9", "10", "11-12", "12-13", "13-14", "15", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "20", "21-22", "22-23", "23-24", "25", "26-27", "27-28", "28-29", "30", "31-32", "32-33", "33-34", "35", "36-37", "37-38", "38-39", "40", "41-42", "42-43", "43-44", "45", "46-47", "47-48", "48-49", "50", "51-52", "52-53", "53-54", "55", "56-57", "57-58", "58-59", "60", "61-62", "62-63", "63-64", "65", "66-67", "67-68", "68-69", "70", "71-72", "72-73", "73-74", "75", "76-77", "77-78", "78-79", "80"]

    
extension UIViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
    let number = array[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = number
    
    return cell    
}
```

}

Теперь условно говоря нужно, чтобы например в первой ячейке по её number в label отображалось соответствующее значение переменной. Я так понимаю, нужно эти 76 переменных уложить в массив, только куда его вставить в коде? и вопрос как обратиться к этому label?
И к ещё одному? Потому что последний берёт своё значение из fileReadManager (там словарь, и если label = item id, то второй  label - item value)

Не понимаю, как вообще их указать, эти тексты? Вообще не могу найти вразумительной информации, везде максимум одно значение и различные функции, а тут получается три. Что посоветуете попробовать?

PS - этот fileReadManager используется во всей программе, этот механизм уже отработан, там всё работает. Вопрос куда передавать значение? Как их передавать? Help

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

```
 guard let root = fileReadManager.fetchDescription() else{
        return
    }
    let dataSource = root.health
    for item in dataSource {
        if item.id == labelOneText {
            healthRootOneText = item.value
        }
            let dataSource = root.health
            for item in dataSource {
        if item.id == labelTwoText {
            healthRootTwoText = item.value
        }
                let dataSource = root.health
                for item in dataSource {
            if item.id == labelText {
                healthRootThreeText = item.value
            
    
    chakraFirstEnergyLabel.text = labelOneText
    chakraSecondEnergyLabel.text = labelTwoText
    chakraThirdEnergyLabel.text = labelText
```

Comment: А за что эти минусы ставятся? Чем я нарушила-то? Если вопрос в том, что сама не пыталась решить - я очень подробно написала, до какого уровня мне удалось доковылять. Да, я дуб, но минусить-то чего? Хоть направьте в какую сторону думать! Мне очень помогли подсказки ранее, хоть и долго соображала, как их использовать именно в моём коде(((

Comment: Не совсем понятно как соотносятся значения в array, 76 переменных и fileReadManager

Comment: То что у вас в array это ключи словаря, возвращаемого fileReadManager?

Comment: Ох и огромная картинка получилась! В общем на картинке в ячейках есть первые цифры - они идут из массива, который уже есть в коде. Потом идут 00 в каждом кружочке - это результаты вычислений, а текст - выбирается из fileReaderManager. Там словарь, каждый айтем имеет id и value. Если 00 = id, соответственно текст = value

Comment: Ох, понимаю, что уже намудрила с три короба, Как теперь распутать... это уже последний момент перед публикацией, а я всё никак не допру

Comment: А каким образом вы соотносите данные из array с данными из словаря? Как определяете какие значения из массива и словаря  вывести вместе в ячейке?

Comment: Вот это я как раз и не знаю, как реализовать. В других местах это делала не в таблице, просто тексты, но там их всего по 3, и конструкция была такая, как я добавила в вопросе. Предлагают перенести обсуждение в чат. Это нужно делать? И как?

Comment: Для начала нужно определить, как логически соотносятся значения из массива наподобие "1-2", "2-3" и тд с данными из словаря, по какому принципу они должны выводиться вместе в ячейках?

Comment: 1-2, 2-3 и т.д. соотносятся с "00" и для каждого "00" есть своя формула в этом же контроллере, они все просчитываются отдельно сразу при viewdidload. И в каждой ячейке происходит соотнесение получившихся и проставившихся 00 со словарём. Сколько получилось в 00 - это id, и ему соответствует уже value для текста. То есть мне нужно сперва передать все результаты вычислений в каждую 00 в каждой ячейке (как это сделать пока загадка) а потом реализовать таким же образом наверно, как в остальных случаях уже работу с базойё

Comment: Мои размышления к этому моменту: если я создам к массиву "1-2" "2-3" и т.д. ещё массив из переменных, значения который просчитываются, то мне нужно как-то добраться до текста в кружочке (как???) чтобы было типа: "00" в ячейке, чей идентификатор равен значению первого элемента первого массива,  получает значение первого элемента второго массива. Кто б ещё научил формулировать правильно задачи((( как это в коде решить-то!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае вам нужно соотнести и связать данные в массиве и словаре, сейчас у вас как я понял они по отдельности и выглядят примерно так

```
    let dict = [
        "33" : "text1",
        "66" : "text2",
        "99" : "text3"
    ]
    
    let array = [
        "0",
        "1-2",
        "2-3"
    ]
```

Если между ключами словаря и данными массива есть однозначное соответствие, то его нужно указать например используя структ, где `category` берется из массива, а остальные данные из словаря.

```
struct Item {
    
    var category: String
    var id: String
    var value: String
    
}
```

После этого можно создать объединяющий массив, здесь он создается вручную, но можно вероятно с помощью цикла, все зависит от реализации, и уже этот массив используем при выводе или фильтруем из него нужные данные (если массив выводится не целиком)

```
    var allItems: [Item]!

    func createItems() {
        allItems = [
            Item(category: "0",   id: "33", value: "text1"),
            Item(category: "1-2", id: "66", value: "text2"),
            Item(category: "2-3", id: "99", value: "text1"),
        ]
    }
```

Полный пример

```
import UIKit

struct Item {
    
    var category: String
    var id: String
    var value: String
    
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var secondTable: UITableView!
    
    let dict = [
        "33" : "text1",
        "66" : "text2",
        "99" : "text3"
    ]
    
    let array = [
        "0",
        "1-2",
        "2-3"
    ]
    
    var allItems: [Item]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        createItems()
        
        secondTable.delegate = self
        secondTable.dataSource = self
        secondTable.reloadData()
    }
    
    func createItems() {
        allItems = [
            Item(category: "0",   id: "33", value: "text1"),
            Item(category: "1-2", id: "66", value: "text2"),
            Item(category: "2-3", id: "99", value: "text1"),
        ]
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allItems.count
    }
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let item = allItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.category
        // ... присваиваем другим лейблам item.id и item.value
        
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Ого! Это очень похоже на решение! Сажусь пробовать!

Comment: Нет. Не выходит каменный цветок. Я видимо замахнулась на что-то вне моего понимания. Вообще не соображаю, что я здесь делаю. Я создала весь массив из 65 items, пришлось переименовать их в ItemOne и внутри тоже добавить, так как перекликалось с менеджером. Но как присвоить значения - даже на это я оказалась неспособна. Хотела ко дню рождения себе подарок сделать - закончить его уже!!! Но видимо придётся пройти заново весь курс.

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно?

Comment: Непонятно, как задать значения.  Что я сделала - в конструкцию Item(category: "0",   id: "33", value: "text1") вместо "33" подставила в каждый элемент свою переменную. А в конце кода попыталась применить тот же самый guard let, что и везде. Но это не сработало, а как по-другому я не знаю))

Comment: @КатаринаМалова подставили переменные и потом вызываете tableView.reloadData() при необходимости, чтобы обновить данные в таблице, для чего guard let? Грузите все данные из файла в массив allItems и потом работаете уже только с ним

Comment: @КатаринаМалова дополните вопрос и покажите как вы используете код из моего примера

Comment: Простите, что долго не отвечаю. Ситуация сейчас не располагает продолжить, смогу вернуться к коду когда всё хоть немного успокоиться тут вокруг. Спасибо огромное за понимание!

Comment: Всё! Заработало! Осталось только понять, что ему не нравится с изображениями, чего ругается и можно было бы публиковать в сторе!!! Но пока подождём, как поведут себя наши братья из-за океана. Безмерно Вам благодарна за помощь! Буду продолжать учиться, хочу как Вы!

Comment: @КатаринаМалова на здоровье